# Manually Supply Referral URL to Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

We have some shopping cart pages which work with both guest and user paths.  We want to allow a user to login at any time during the process but don't really want to create yet another login page.  I'd prefer that we can simply redirect the user to the existing login and tell Spring Security what URL to come back to.

I know this happens automatically when sessions timeout and/or protected pages are requested without a session, but is there a way I can give the URL to Spring Security myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a simple return-to URL to retrieve the cart, then you are probably best to implement that yourself in an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#form-login-flow-handling). You can look at the source for `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and its parent for inspiration.

The default login mechanism uses the `RequestCache` and a `SavedRequest`, but that is intended to actually replay a request which would not otherwise be authorised. That's probably overkill in your case.

Comment: What I don't understand about this solution is that it is a success handler and I need to get something into Spring Security to tell it what URL to come back to.  So even if I created my own handler, if I don't tell it what to do after success, the point is moot.  And I'm not always coming in from that direction.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question then. You seemed to just be asking how to redirect to a known URL after loggin in. If so, then all you need is some way of storing the URL to return to before you redirect to the login page. How you do that is really up to you. If you already have a session for the cart, then the obvious place to store it is in the session. The only thing you have to "get into Spring Security" is the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. In the handler implementation you simply retrieve the stored URL and redirect to it.

Comment: Well, yea, I've done that.  But I was actually looking for something a bit more integrated.  Good enough for now though.

Comment: @Gregg also checkout the `useReferer` field in `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.