# Spring security with two realms, first default-target-url is never invoked

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1 and have configured two realms, one for admin users and a second for other users like this:

```
<!-- Configure realm for administration users -->
<http pattern="/admin/**" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/adminLogin" default-target-url="/adminWelcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<!--  Configure realm for normal users -->
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Everything works fine, except that on all successful logins - user and admin - the "welcome" url is invoked.  The "adminWelcome" url is never invoked on the admin login.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The `pattern` attribute in the `<http>` element means that *only* requests which match that pattern will be passed through that filter chain.

In particular, the submission of the login page (which is typically to `/j_spring_security_check` will go through the second chain, which handles all other requests. So it will be processed by the login filter created by the second `form-login` element and the user will be redirected to `/welcome` after logging in.

It sounds like you would be better using a single filter chain to handle all requests, with an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10608414/241990) to choose where the user should be redirected to after logging in.

#### Update

If you want to configure the URL to which your admin login page is submitted to make the login request go through the first filter chain, use `login-processing-url`:

```
<http pattern="/admin/**" >
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login login-page="/adminLogin" login-processing-url="/admin/login.do" default-target-url="/adminWelcome"
    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Then modify your admin login form to submit to that URL.

Comment: I have two login forms: adminLogin and login. Entering "/adminLogin" in a browser does bring up the adminLogin page. But a successful login is redirected to /welcome instead of being redirected to /adminWelcome.  And the Spring docs suggest I should be able to set up multiple <http> elements.

Comment: `/adminLogin` will also go through the second filter chain, but will not be affected as you have no security constraints which match this pattern, so the page will be rendered as you would expect. You can set up multiple `<http>` elements, but it is more complicated and you need to think carefully about what requests you will be making and which filter chain will handle each request. If you are really sure you need two blocks, then you can configure the URL which the login form is submitted to using `login-processing-url`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the complications with multiple <http> elements.  I tried your suggestion to use login-processing-url, but that didn't work for me, so went with a single <http> element.  In my controller for /welcome, I check the role of the user and handle it accordingly.